# How to link GLEW and GLFW and OpenGL to MingW's g++

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw, glfw, glew

I am doing a course on OpenGL.

So I have run my project in Visual Studio 2019 and it works.

What I needed to do in Visual Studio was:

1. Add GLEW's and GLFW's additional **include** directories. (when you download the libraries it is simply the location of the include file)
2. Add GLEW's and GLFW's additional **library** directories. (lib folder locations)
3. Add the additional **dependencies**. (opengl32.lib, glew32.lib, glfw3.lib)
4. **Copy** and paste **GLEW.dll** into the project files, next to main.cpp.

And I run my code and it works.

But I don't want to use Visual Studio 2019, I would much rather work in Notepad++ or VSCode, what I really want is to just make a project out of **pure** notepad and compile it with the **new Windows Terminal**.

My question: 
How can I do all of the things I did in visual studio 2019 from **Power Shell**?

I heard that MingW comes with its own power shell or command prompt, I imagine I need to find it and give it some commands to link everything up before I start coding.

Where do I find MingW's power shell equivalent and what commands do I need to type?

I have been stuck on this for ages now and could not find any information about it online. (except for what -L and -l does, but these are not **power shell** commands)

Comment: Note that when you switch to mingw you will likely need to get mingw binaries for your third party libraries.

Comment: There is this: [http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS)

Comment: Well, I'm sure I don't need to download anything extra to use a library. That would be pretty weird.

Comment: No but you probably need different binaries because `c++` compilers are binary incompatible. Visual Studio 2015 to 2019 are compatible with each other but no other version of Visual Studio or any other compiler execept for clang when its in a special compatibility mode.

Comment: Here is what I was talking about: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Here is probably where you need to start to compile c++ code from visual studio on the command line: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=vs-2019)

Comment: I'm confused, I don't wanna use visual studio... Sooo, maybe I'm just way too inexperienced to understand any of this, this is the first time I have heard of binaries. Would this all be easier if I used Microsoft cl compiler?

Comment: Oh! this might help. :/ So MinGW doesn't come with a way to link files to it? instead, I need to download extra stuff?.. Ok, I'll go read this now.

Comment: It would be much easier if you just use the Visual Studio IDE directly. Although its good to learn these topics they are not beginner friendly.

Comment: ***So MinGW doesn't come with a way to link files to it?***  It does. If you are building a single c++ file with no external library dependencies like glew you may find it easy to build `g++ myfile.cpp -o myfile.exe`

Comment: Here is information on how to build glew using mingw: [https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#msys2mingw-w64](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#msys2mingw-w640)

Comment: Here is info on how to build a simple application with mingw from the command line [http://www.mingw.org/node/78/revisions/255/view](http://www.mingw.org/node/78/revisions/255/view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MingGW](http://www.mingw.org/) and [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php)
compilers are Windows commandline tools. They are Windows ports of (some of)
the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers. [tdm-gcc](https://jmeubank.github.io/tdm-gcc/) is yet another choice.

Commandine tools for any operating
system don't need their own shell. You can run them in any shell you've got
on that operating system. On Windows today
you have a choice of at least PowerShell and the old CMD shell.

The MinGW project provides, as well as its GCC toolchain, a minimal unix-like
environment for Windows called MSYS, which includes a shell. *You don't need
MSYS to run the compiler.*

As long as the GCC tools can be located in
the value of the `PATH` environment variable that is operative in
the shell at compiletime, then you run the compiler at the shell prompt:

```
>gcc [options...]
>g++ [options...]
```

the same way it is run on any operating system. If you want to work with a GCC toolchain then the question:

> How can I do all of the things I did in visual studio 2019 from Power Shell?

is simply the question, *How do you run GCC?* That's a question of
sweeping generality. You need to study relevant [books](https://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/index.html)
and [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Very sketchily, if you want to compile and link a C++ program that has source files `main.cpp` and `other.cpp` and depends on libraries
`foo` and `bar` that have their C++ APIs defined in header files and are implemented in DLLs,
you will do it with commands of the following form:

To compile the source files to object files:

```
>g++ -c -o main.obj main.cpp -I/path/to/foo/header/files -I/path/to/bar/header/files [any other compilation options....]
>g++ -c -o other.obj other.cpp -I/path/to/foo/header/files -I/path/to/bar/header/files [any other compilation options....]
```

To link the object files and libraries to make an excutable program:

```
>g++ -o prog main.obj other.obj -L/path/to/foo_dll -L/maybe/a/different/path/to/bar_dll -lfoo -lbar [any other linkage options...]
```

And if all that is successful then the program will be `prog.exe` and you can run it:

```
>prog
```

just like you ran `g++`, provided that `foo.dll` and `bar.dll` can be found at runtime by [the OS loader's DLL search protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

As I think you appreciate, in real life nobody builds programs by typing the all the
commands in a shell except for instructional purposes. They use a build system or an IDE to automate it. But it is true that building programs though the medium of a build system or IDE presents fewer difficulties if you do it with a basic grasp of how the tools behind it work.

Comment: O
M
G
Amazing!

I will add your links to the things I must read and will read them later, it looks like this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: To maybe explain some of the confusion, in MSYS2, there is a thing called "MinGW-w64 Win64 shell" or "MINGW64 shell". It means a shell session that is started with MSYSTEM=MINGW64 predefined in the environment so that everything is set up for native compilation with the x86_64-w64-mingw32 toolchain. (Analogously for 32 bits.)

Comment: I have finally got my project up and running, it took a long time to figure out all the things I needed to do to finally compile my project. On-top of figuring out the compiler commands I also needed to download CMake and Make, and also I needed to add -lgdi32 for glfw3... A library that depends on another library... 0_0 It was pretty depressing just a few moments ago when I thought it should be compiling when it wasn't, I thought I would never be able to compile other library's, but I got there in the end, thank all of you for the support.